# How to read .ARC files from the Heritrix crawler using Python?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I looked at the Heritrix documentation website, and they listed a Python .ARC file reader. However, it is 404 not found when I clicked on it. http://crawler.archive.org/articles/developer_manual/arcs.html

Does anyone else know any Heritrix ARC reader that uses Python?

(I asked this question before, but closed it due to inaccuracy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing a little Googling can't find:
http://archive-access.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/archive-access/archive-access/projects/hedaern/